# Why doesn't a negative number modulo a vector size give a negative number?

Tags: c++, modulus, integer-promotion

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  int i = -4;

  cout << i << endl;
  cout << v.size() << endl;
  cout << i % v.size() << endl;
  cout << -4 % 7 << endl;
}
```

The above code prints:

```
-4
7
5
-4
```

Can someone please explain why `i % v.size()` prints `5` instead of `-4`? I'm guessing it has something to do with `vector.size()`, but unsure what the underlying reasoning is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you for 'i % 7' and '-4 % v.size()'  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modulo operator with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values)

Comment: @Spencer: I think that's only half the problem. The other half is that `v.size()` is `unsigned`, causing weird integer promotion problems

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ size\_t modulus operation with negative operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337196/c-size-t-modulus-operation-with-negative-operand), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523401/why-mod-operation-return-0-when-one-is-size-t-type-and-the-other-is-0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299317/why-does-the-c-modulo-operator-return-0-for-1-str-size)

Comment: @MooingDuck which can be rolled into the characterization of unspecified behavior.

Comment: @Nick that doesn't even mention unspecified behavior once.  It shouldn't be the canonical dupe.

Comment: @Spencer Of course it doesn't... integer conversion is well defined.

Comment: @Nick Integer conversion is an unimportant detail here. It's the unspecified nature of the behavior of `%` with negative arguments that causes the problem.

Comment: @Spencer There _aren't_ negative arguments for the case in question, they're both converted to unsigned. (if that didn't make sense, the question is explicitly about the `i % v.size()` case or `signed % unsigned`, the signed value gets converted to an unsigned type before the `%` operation actually takes place, hence... nothing unexpected here)

Comment: @Spencer: There's no undefined behavior. Integer promotion is well defined, and `%` with negative arguments is well defined as well.

Comment: @MooingDuck I didn't say "undefined", I said "unspecified". But even that's wrong, it's actually "implementation-defined" _because [size_t is implementation defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)_, and even with the integer conversion you shouldn't expect any particular result across platforms.

Answer (score 31):

The operands of `%` undergo the *usual arithmetic conversions* to bring them to a common type, before the division is performed.  If the operands were `int` and `size_t`, then the `int` is converted to `size_t`.

If `size_t` is 32-bit then `-4` would become `4294967292` and then the result of the expression is `4294957292 % 7` which is actually `0`.

If `size_t` is 64-bit then `-4` would become 18,446,744,073,709,551,612  and the result of this `% 7` is `5` which you saw.

So actually we can tell from this output that your system has 64-bit size_t.

Answer (score 9):

In C++ the modulus operator is defined so that the following is true for *all* integers except for b == 0:

```
(a/b)*b + a%b == a
```

So it is forced to be consistent with the integer division, which from C++ 11 onwards truncates to zero even for negative numbers. Hence everything is well defined even for negative numbers.

However, in your case you have an signed / unsigned division (because .size() returns unsigned) and the usual signed/unsigned rules apply. This means that in this case all arguments are converted to unsigned before the operation is carried out (see also Ruslan's comment).

So -4 is converted to unsigned (and becomes a very large number) and then modulo is carried out.

You can also see this as 5 is not a correct answer for -4 modulo 7 with any definition of integer division (3 would be correct).

Arithmetic rules with C and C++ are not intuitive.

Comment: _"This means that all arguments are converted to unsigned"_ — note that in general this isn't true: e.g. `10U/-3LL` has type `signed long long` (provided `long long` is longer than `unsigned`, which is usually true). Yes, the rules are not intuitive indeed.

Comment: The identity `a/b*b+a%b==a` except for b==0 goes back to C++98, and C89 (thus ARM). C99 and C++11 did change / and % with a _negative_ operand to always round-to-zero (aka truncate) instead of implementation-defined rounding, but as you (and others) correctly say in this case the operands are forced to unsigned, and (when used) are not negative.

Comment: @Ruslan, dave_thompson_085: Thanks I updated my answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 4):

Because `v.size` return `size_t`.

```
cout << -4 % size_t(7) << endl; // 5
```

Take a look [modulo-operator-with-negative-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values)

UPD: and [signed-int-modulo-unsigned-int-produces-nonsense-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293686/signed-int-modulo-unsigned-int-produces-nonsense-results)

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the type of `v.size()`, which is an unsigned type. Due to integer promotion, this means that the result will also be treated as unsigned, despite `i` being a signed type.

I am assuming you are compiling on 64 bit. This means that in addition to promotion to unsigned, the result will also be of the 64 bit type `unsigned long long`. Step by step:

1. `unsigned long long _i = (unsigned long long)-4; // 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC!`
2. `unsigned long long result = _i % (unsigned long long)7; // 5`

Since presumably you want to preserve the signedness of `i`, in this case it is enough to cast `v.size()` to a signed type to prevent the promotion to unsigned:
`i % (int)v.size()` will give `-4`.

Comment: It might be `unsigned long` if that is 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

From cppreference on [Usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) and [C++ standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.5.3)

> Otherwise (the signedness is different): If the unsigned type has conversion rank greater than or equal to the rank of the signed type, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type.

`-4` is `signed` and `7` is `size_t` which is an `unsigned` type, so `-4` is converted to `unsigned` first and then modulus is carried out.

With that mind, if you break it down, you will immediately see what is happening:

```cpp
size_t s = -4; // s = 18446744073709551612 on a 64 bit system
size_t m = 7;
std::cout << s % m << '\n'; //5
```

The results might be different for a 32-bit system.

`cout << -4 % 7 << endl;` still prints `-4`. Why? It's because the type of both `-4` and `7` is `int`.

C++ standard §5.13.2.3 [Type of an integer literal](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#3)

> The type of an integer-literal is the first type in the list in Table 8 corresponding to its optional integer-suffix in which its value can be represented. An integer-literal is a prvalue.

**Table 8: Types of integer-literals** without suffix:

```
    int
    long int
    long long int
```

So, `-4` and `7` both are `int` in this case and hence the result of modulo is `-4`.